# Follow a redirect url for Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm using the following code:

```
Future<DataResponse> login({required String userId}) async {
    final headers = {
      'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': '*/*',
    };
    final uri = Uri.parse("${Env.BASE_URL}/login?userId=$userId");
    print("url status: $uri");
    final request = http.Request('GET', uri)..followRedirects = true..headers.addAll(headers);
    final response = await request.send();
    return DataResponse(statusCode: response.statusCode, message: '', data: response.stream);
  }
```

The server has the following code:

```
app.get("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  const options = {
    accessType: "offline",
    scope: [
      "email",
      "profile",
    ],
    state: req.query.userId as string | undefined,
  };

  passport.authenticate("google", options)(req, res, next);
});

app.get("/login/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", {}), async (req, res) => {
      {
        const user = req.user as (iUser | undefined);
        if (!user) {
          // Redirect to login page
          return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
        }

        const databaseId = req.query.state as string | undefined;

        if (!databaseId) {
          return res.status(422).send("No user id was provided");
        }

        // state comes from the youtube/login route
        user.databaseId = databaseId;
        user.service = "google";

        try {
          await database.upsertUser(user);
          return res.status(204).send();
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Error: ", e);
          return res.status(500).send(e);
        }
      }
    });
```

When running the web application, I'm not getting any redirect, however, when I copy and paste the same URL into my web browser I get the Google login redirect. How can I show this URL callback to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You might look closer at what the web server is responding with and how the redirect happens.  It may be that from a web browser the "redirect" happens by the web page returning a "meta refresh" or it includes some javascript that loads a new page. What is the value of response.statusCode that request.send() is returning?

Comment: I've updated the question with the server-side code, if successful I'm returning 204, should I return something else?

Comment: According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpClientRequest/followRedirects.html the followRedirects only is for response codes 301, 302, 303, 307, and 308.

Comment: Should you be parsing the response and then opening the URL in a browser window?  You can do so with launchUrl.  Would either of these packages be helpful: https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2 or https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in

Comment: The thing is that I need just permission to do backend stuff, however, I have multiple services, which means that the user would have to log in through a lot of services. I'll try to change the response codes, however, where should I add this code, inside the login endpoint or the callback?